# Replace a git remote without affecting branches

Tags: git, git-remote

I am mid-development into a project and due to DevOps changes there is suddenly the need to re-connect to the remote (with a new URL). What are the steps that I need to take to remove the old remote and establish connection with the new one without ruining my unmerged branches?

I have tried updating the remote URL using:

`git remote set-url origin codecommit::us-west-2://myrepo`

but getting this error when fetching from master:

```
fatal: repository 'https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo/' not found
```

Am I missing something?

As background, the CodeCommit repo that I used to work with has been changed to require federated access. So I want to use git-remote-codecommit (GRC) with the corresponding URL instead of the old standard HTTPS URL.

Comment: @1615903 `git remote set-url` doesn't seem to work unfortunately. Doing fetch gives this error: fatal: repository "https://git-codecommit..../" not found

Comment: That means your repository URL is wrong, not that set-url doesn't work.

Comment: @1615903 You're right. The credentials weren't being recognized by the new remote. I fixed it and was able to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *before* changing origin, you can check if an URL work with:

```
git ls-remote <newURL>
```

You can execute that command anywhere, and as long as it does not fully work... you don't need to worry about `git remote set-url origin`.

Second, I know about this [codecommit AWS endpoints (HTTPS or SSH)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/regions.html#regions-git), but not about "federated".
Double-check the process described in  "[Using Federated Identities with AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-federated-identities-with-aws-codecommit/)", especially the `/home/ec2-user/.aws` directory content.

The [OP Mossi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936026/mossi) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480402/replace-a-git-remote-without-affecting-branches#comment119294379_67481931):

> Turned out the IAM role that the AWS Credential Helper needed had disappeared from my environment variables.
>
> I added it back and I was able to connect to the repo using the GRC URL.  In short `set-url` was the solution.

Comment: This was helpful. Turned out the IAM role that the AWS Credential Helper needed had disappeared from my environment variables. I added it back and I was able to connect to the repo using the GRC URL. In short `set-url` was the solution.

Comment: Great! Well done.